# Graph of a circuit comprising coupled inductors

Tags: graph

In case an arbitrary circuit contains coupled inductors, the system impedance (conductance) matrix is not diagonal. Is there a way to relate such a matrix to adjacency/incidence/Laplacian matrix of the circuit graph?

Also, is it possible to adjust the circuit graph in case inductors are coupled?

[image]

In the exemplary circuit labeled with A, where Minc denotes the incidence matrix, one can set the Kirchhoff voltage law for every branch as

\begin{equation*}
M_\mathrm{inc} 
\begin{bmatrix}
V_\mathrm{A} \\
V_\mathrm{B} \\
V_\mathrm{C} 
\end{bmatrix}=
-\begin{bmatrix}
u_\mathrm{A} \\
u_\mathrm{B} \\
u_\mathrm{C} 
\end{bmatrix}
+ Z_\mathrm{br} \begin{bmatrix}
i_\mathrm{A} \\
i_\mathrm{B} \\
i_\mathrm{C} 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

However, in the circuit from (b), impedance matrix needs to be established as

\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
Z_\mathrm{br}
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
L_\mathrm{s} & L_\mathrm{m} & L_\mathrm{m} \\
L_\mathrm{m} & L_\mathrm{s} & L_\mathrm{m} \\
L_\mathrm{m} & L_\mathrm{m} & L_\mathrm{s} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

It is obvious that the branch currents are equal, which diagonalizes the matrix Zbr. However, how to show this using adjacency/incidence/Laplacian matrix (or any other matrix)??

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Also, is it possible to adjust the circuit graph in case inductors are coupled?

Yes, just add the mutual coupling terms ([this example](https://cdn.selinc.com/assets/Literature/Publications/Technical%20Papers/6090.pdf?v=20151125-185442) gives the idea).  If the mutual coupling is symmetrical then the resulting impedance matrix will be symmetrical.

Comment: Thank you! However, this approach has two constraints:
1. It is assumed that the currents inside the circuit are purely AC, which does not have to be the case (there are applications where both DC and AC currents can flow through such a structure)
2. It applicable to a 3PH circuit. What if the circuit graph has more than three branches (e.g. 6/9/etc.)

Comment: That specific case i referenced is for AC steady state three phase, but the approach is not limited.  The mutual coupling depends on geometry, it doesn’t care if the current is steady state AC or a changing DC current.  Instead of impedance use Ldi/dt.  All that is really happening with mutual coupling is that another current (other than the current flowing in your element) is inducing a voltage in your element.  Check out this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/network_theory/network_theory_coupled_circuits.htm).